# Presenting/dismissing modal view controller which contains a table makes the table go down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I present/dismiss modal view controller with tableview in it. Each presenting/dismissing causes the table to move down, leaving a gap between the table and top of the view. so each time i present after a dismiss, i see my table going down one row-height distance . keeping the routine, the table really 'leaves ' the screen. Please help.

Comment: any code or screen shot of what the problem is?

Comment: It sounds like you're programatically resizing/repositioning something in the `viewWillAppear` method. Can you post some code from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this a few times and did the workaround (re-setting the frame) because of time pressure, but the last time I ran into it I found a real fix.  Instead of creating your top level view controller in code (if it is), try having it be created in the UIWindow and IBOutlet it to the AppDelegate instead.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XIB, check autoresize option of your table view in the Interface Builder

Comment: Then make sure you call myTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.

Comment: didn't solve the issue. i tried both in the tableview controller method's implementation (viewWilLoad and others) and inside the implementation of the method which brings up the modal view.